# Assign weighted value to rows using SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sample, weighted

I have a table of customers that I want to assign a test group. I want to assign a test group based on weighted values.

Example:

```
Group 1 - 50%
Group 2 - 25%
Group 3 - 20%
Group 4 - 5%
```

Result:

| customer_id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | group 1 |
| 2 | group 4 |
| 3 | group 1 |
| 4 | group 2 |
| 5 | group 1 |
| 6 | group 1 |
| 7 | group 2 |
| 8 | group 1 |
| 9 | group 3 |
| 10 | group 1 |

Comment: Cannot understand your question

Answer (score 0):

If you shuffle the rows randomly you can then split based on the cumulative frequencies. While this works neatly when the fractions are neat I'm not sure if this will meet the most general case you've got.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(*) over () * 1.0 as cnt,
        row_number() over (order by random()) * 1.0 as rn
    from T
)
select customer_id,
    case when rn / cnt <= 0.50 then 'Group 1'
         when rn / cnt <= 0.75 then 'Group 2'
         when rn / cnt <= 0.95 then 'Group 3'
         when rn / cnt <= 1.00 then 'Group 4'
    end as grp
from data;
```